# Is it a good thing to use Null as flag in composed objects?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a situation in my application. I am getting response from a service. I need to convert and save the response sometimes in cache sometimes in Database or some other media. There could be a scenario as well where I need not to persist the response but only need to convert the respone and return the object. I have implemented following design:

```
public class Response { }

class MyData { }

interface IPersistance 
{
    public void PersistData(MyData data);
}

public class DBPersitance : IPersistance 
{
    public void PersistData(MyData data) { }
}

public class CachePersitance : IPersistance
{
    public void PersistData(MyData data) { }
}

public class MySeviceData
{
    private IPersistance persistence;

    public MySeviceData(IPersistance persistance)
    {
        _persistance = persistance;
    }

    public MyData GetServiceData(Response reponseXML)
    {
        MyData output = new MyData();

        // Here output object is filled with data from responseXML

        // Object persistance as defined in constructor
        if(_persistance!=null)
            _persistance.PersistData(output);

        return output;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyData output = new MyData();
        Response responseXML = new Response() ;

        //Case 1: Cache the response
        CachePersitance cache = new CachePersitance();
        MySeviceData srvData = new MySeviceData(cache);
        output = srvData.GetServiceData(responseXML);

        //Case 2: Write the response in Database
        DBPersitance db = new DBPersitance();
        MySeviceData srvData = new MySeviceData(db);
        output = srvData.GetServiceData(responseXML);

        //Case 3: No need to persist. Only Convert and return the response
        MySeviceData srvData = new MySeviceData(null);
        output = srvData.GetServiceData(responseXML);
    }
}
```

In the above implementation, In the scenario, where I only need to convert the object (no persiatance), I have passed `null` persistance object. Is this approach correct? Could anybody suggest any better design for this kind of requirement?

Comment: You could add a parameterless constructor instead of passing null. But this really becomes a question of style and opinion, which isn't a really good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: One school of thinking is to avoid `if` to check for `null` whenever possible. An empty `IPersistance` (called for example `NoPersistance`) implementation would work. If you provide an overload where it's default then it'll be even smoother.

Answer (score 1):

One school of thinking is to avoid `if`s to check for `null` whenever possible. We may agree or not (and this will be very opinion based, IMO it's good but *cum grano salis*, `null` is not always evil when it carries *information*).

To use an empty class instead of `null` will make obvious the intent when you read code (*Persistance is null? What it means? Default one or no one? If default one then what's this default?*).

An empty `IPersistance` (called for example `NoPersistance`) implementation would work. You  may even provide a constructor overload without parameters (like in next example) if this is most common case (and you don't need to make it explicit, in that case just remove it).

```
public class NoPersitance : IPersistance {
    public void PersistData(MyData data) {
        // Nothing to do
    }
}

public class MySeviceData {
    private IPersistance _persistance;

    public MySeviceData(IPersistance persistance) {
        if (persistance == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("persistance");

        _persistance = persistance;
    }

    public MySeviceData() : this(new NoPersistance()) {
    }

    public MyData GetServiceData(Response reponseXML) {
        Debug.Assert(_persistance != null);

        MyData output = new MyData();
        // Fill your object's data

        // Store object somewhere
        _persistance.PersistData(output);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Used like this (no parameters means no persistance, can be documented in `MyServiceData` constructor overload):

```
MySeviceData srvData = new MySeviceData();
output = srvData.GetServiceData(responseXML);
```

Or like this:

```
MySeviceData srvData = new MySeviceData(new NoPersistance());
output = srvData.GetServiceData(responseXML);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why we need the overloaded constructor here?

Comment: @user3169906 It's just there to allow syntax of first example (no parameters = no persistance) as a shortcut for syntax of second example (where you explictly say to use NoPersistance class). If you don't need such shortcut (or you want to always make explicit this choice) then you can simply remove that overload and go happy.